# Graph Algorithm Idea

Tags: algorithm, graph

Hi can anyone give a hint as to what is the underlying graph problem for this one ?

https://icpcarchive.ecs.baylor.edu/external/64/6450.pdf

I personally think about it like this:

Sort the number of nodes of the graph by decreasing number of edges. Then choose the top most one. After that ignore all the nodes that this top one was connected to. And choose the next one after that.

For first test case

Answer is 1 because the graph is fully connected and choosing any node will make sure all other nodes are covered.

For second test case

We can choose node 5 (this will cover node1, 2 and 4).Then we can choose node 3. This way all nodes are covered.

The problem is that this approach looks to me just made up one. This is not any graph algorithm.

It will be great if someone can give a hint. Thanks.

VVV

Comment: This is a NP-c problem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_independent_set

Comment: If its an NP complete problem then how can they ask in programming contest?

Comment: @VVV NP-c problems are solveable, just not likely you can do this fast. If it's a programming contest I don't think you should ask for this kind of help.

Comment: Elyashiv, It's an old programming contest from 2013, I am just practicing graph algorithms. Also it does look like Maximal Independent Set Problem. Thanks.

Comment: still NPC... no luck.

Comment: @VVV: Since *n < 20*, DP with bitmasks works. Just think about it this way: Every user reaches a subset of other users, including himself. How can we combine a minimal number of subsets such that the whole set of users is covered.

Comment: @elyashiv: Since n < 20, it's easy to solve

Comment: @NiklasB. No. The problem is NPC in though it's hard to solve. Because n < 20 is won't take forever (approximately)

Comment: @elyashiv: Hah? Sure it's NPC, that doesn't mean I can't write an O(n * 2^n) algorithm for it that solves it in under a second with the given constraints. Also, I think you mean NP-hard instead of NPC, because it's not a decision problem.

Comment: @VVV it is not that impossible. A few times we got NP-complete problems in top coder(one time it was even a 500 pointer) because the author thought he got a solution(proven to be wrong after the contest). Also in one of my regionals there was a NP complete problem with constraints n<=1000, while after the competition it turned out all tests were for n<=15. Maybe people try to get a polynomial solution to an NP-complete problem for free ;) BTW you are lucky enough to have small constraints so there really **is** a solution.

Comment: @Ivaylo: "NP complete problem with constraints n<=1000, while after the competition it turned out all tests were for n<=15". That's a very poorly set problem then...

Comment: Looks like vertex cover for the dual graph. It's not max independent set - consider the example where A and B are friends, A-C, A-D, B-E, B-F

Comment: @NiklasB. tell me about it. We had really bad problem set and a lot of problems with the machine too. Too bad we were practicing like crazy before that and really thought we stood a chance.

Comment: @clwhisk: It's known as the dominating set problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [Dominating Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set) problem, which is NP-hard, so unless P = NP, there is no polynomial solution for it.

Note that *n < 20*, so luckily we can still solve it fast enough. For every user *0 ≤ i < n*, let's represent its neighborhood by a bitmask *b(i)* with *n* bits that has all the bits set that represent users reachable from *i* via paths of length *≤ 1*. We can precompute *b(i)* in *O(n²)*.

Let's define *f(i,m)* to be the minimal number of users needed to reach all users represented by the bitmask *m*, posting only on the walls of users with index *≤ i*. We can compute *f* using the following algorithm:

```
f(i,m) = ∞  for all i, m
f(0, 0) = 0
f(0, b(0)) = 1
for i = 1 to n - 1:
    for m = 0 to 2^n - 1:
        f(i, m) = min(f(i, m), f(i - 1, m))
        f(i, m | b(i)) = min(f(i, m | b(i)), f(i - 1, m) + 1)
```

The answer is *f(n - 1, 2^n - 1)*. Runtime: *O(n * 2^n)*

Comment: Thanks Niklas, the description on Wikipedia makes sense with the problem description.

Comment: Actually i am a newbie in graph so have studied things like bfs, dfs, spanning tree, shortest path etc. so I was trying to solve it with one of these but it turns out to be completely different. Thanks for the detailed explanation and you are right n < 20 should have made me think towards NP complete graph algorithms as well. Thanks.

Comment: @VVV: From the input constraints you can often tell approximately the time complexity that is expected by the problem setter. 20 * 2^20 is 20 * 10^6, which is a typical time bound, coupled with a low constant factor.

Comment: Thanks Niklas. I got AC for that program and I like your innovative way of applying the OR operation on the neighbors of a node to check if all nodes are reachable or not. But there is no way that I could have come up with an idea like this. How did you come with an idea of storing the neighbors as bits instead of normal adjacency list? I mean I need ideas like these to solve these kind of problems. Where can I learn these kind of tricks from? We were only taught to store graphs as adjacency lists / matrix.